# Can someone suggest some good reads on OAS and Spread Duration?

Tags: fixed-income, finance, bond, finance-mathematics, financial-engineering

I have been through the CITI Yield book paper and the OAS by Barclays. Is there is anything else that tackles this topic?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Boyarchenko (2014): Understanding Mortgage Spreads .

Miller, Tom (2007): Introduction to Option-Adjusted Spread Analysis.